# How to convert only the outer table of some nested tables into text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have one table inside another table. Both these table contain texts. I want to convert only the outer table into text while keeping the inner table intact. The usual convert table to text option converts all the tables into texts.

Comment: You need to convert all the table to text and then convert the text that was the inner table back to a table.

Comment: @David, in this way the original formatting of the inner table is lost. What I am doing instead, which does not seem efficient to me, is cut the inner table first, convert the outer table to text, and then paste back the inner table.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution, and then, looking at the "convert table to text" dialog box, I saw this tickable option "convert nested tables", selected by default. Once de-selected, it only removes the outer table.
It's funny because even in the Office support article about converting tables, in Portuguese, this option is not presented.

Comment: When I try this (on Word 2013), the “Convert nested tables” checkbox is disabled (grayed out) unless I select “Separate text with paragraph marks”, which runs counter to the spirit of converting a table to text (it destroys the tabular structure of the information, making each cell a separate paragraph, with no indication of where the row boundaries were). Are you able to convert the outer table (and *only* the outer table) to text, and get the cells in a row into a paragraph, separated by tabs or commas? What version of Word are you using?